# Show snackbar message after widget rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to do login page (do the transaction in some Future function) and show the error message by Snackbar.

1. Click login
2. Show loading
3. Future transaction done (back to original page), and then show the error message

Here is the flow I want to achieve (the last part failed):
[image]

**I don't know how to show the snackBar correctly using the message from future.**

showSnackBar need `BuildContext` but the context inside the signIn page seems no longer valid anymore after the message come back from Future.

I am now using package [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) and [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod) for the state management.

**My State**

```
class MyState{
  MyState({this.data,this.isLoading});
  final bool isLoading;
  final String data;

  MyState copyWith({data, isLoading}) => MyState(data: data, isLoading: isLoading);
}
```

**State control and provider**

`Future<String> getData()` fetch data and return error message

```
class MyStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<MyState> {
  MyStateNotifier(MyState state) : super(state);

  Future<String> getData() async {
    state = state.copyWith(isLoading: true);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)); // simulate getting data
    state = state.copyWith(isLoading: false, data: 'some data');
    return 'error message';
  }
}

final myStateProvider = StateNotifierProvider<MyStateNotifier>((ref) {
  return MyStateNotifier(MyState(data: null, isLoading: false));
});
```

**My widget**

`myState.isLoading`: show loading page or sign in page

```
class WidgetA extends HookWidget {
  const WidgetA({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final myState = useProvider(myStateProvider.state);
    return Center(
      child: myState.isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : SignInPage(),
    );
  }
}

class SignInPage extends HookWidget {
  const SignInPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        context.read(myStateProvider).getData().then(
          (message) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
          },
        );
      },
      child: Text('login'),
    );
  }
}
```

I use showSnackBar inside **then** after **getData()**, but it show the error message:

```
E/flutter ( 6869): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a 
deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter ( 6869): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter ( 6869): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
E/flutter ( 6869): #0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3938:9)
E/flutter ( 6869): #1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3952:6)
E/flutter ( 6869): #2      Element.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4044:12)
E/flutter ( 6869): #3      debugCheckHasScaffoldMessenger.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:142:17)
E/flutter ( 6869): #4      debugCheckHasScaffoldMessenger (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:154:4)
E/flutter ( 6869): #5      ScaffoldMessenger.of (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:218:12)
E/flutter ( 6869): #6      SignInPage.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_app_test2/main.dart:171:35)
E/flutter ( 6869): #7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter ( 6869): #8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 6869): #9      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
E/flutter ( 6869): #10     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
E/flutter ( 6869): #11     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
E/flutter ( 6869): #12     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
E/flutter ( 6869): #13     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:254:13)
E/flutter ( 6869): #14     MyStateNotifier.getData (package:flutter_app_test2/main.dart)
E/flutter ( 6869): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Reason : Because `SignInPage` disappear after click `login` button
Quick fix is use `ScaffoldMessenger` and provide `scaffoldMessengerKey` then call `scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));` 
code snippet

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> scaffoldMessengerKey =
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      key: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      child: Scaffold(
      
...
context.read(myStateProvider).getData().then(
          (message) {
            scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
          },
        );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/all.dart';

class MyState {
  MyState({this.data, this.isLoading});
  final bool isLoading;
  final String data;

  MyState copyWith({data, isLoading}) =>
      MyState(data: data, isLoading: isLoading);
}

class MyStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<MyState> {
  MyStateNotifier(MyState state) : super(state);

  Future<String> getData() async {
    state = state.copyWith(isLoading: true);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)); // simulate getting data
    state = state.copyWith(isLoading: false, data: 'some data');
    return 'error message';
  }
}

final myStateProvider = StateNotifierProvider<MyStateNotifier>((ref) {
  return MyStateNotifier(MyState(data: null, isLoading: false));
});

void main() {
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> scaffoldMessengerKey =
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      key: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('example')),
        body: WidgetA(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetA extends HookWidget {
  const WidgetA({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myState = useProvider(myStateProvider.state);
    return Center(
      child: myState.isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : SignInPage(),
    );
  }
}

class SignInPage extends HookWidget {
  const SignInPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        context.read(myStateProvider).getData().then(
          (message) {
            scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
          },
        );
      },
      child: Text('login'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to await you getData() request and return the message in a variable, then call the snackbar.  You're trying to call the snackbar inside the future call.  This can't be done on the UI.

```
  final message = await context.read(myStateProvider).getData();
   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
```

Comment: That's what I facing now. If it is a bad design and can't be done on the UI, what your suggestion?

Comment: What I just mentioned.  Get the return message first, then show the snackbar.  It will work inside the onTap method, just not inside the future method.